# DataArray case-insensitive match that returns the index value of the match

Tags: regex, grep, match, julia, case-insensitive

I have a DataFrame inside of a function:

```
using DataFrames

myservs = DataFrame(serverName = ["elmo", "bigBird", "Oscar", "gRover", "BERT"],
                    ipAddress = ["12.345.6.7", "12.345.6.8", "12.345.6.9", "12.345.6.10", "12.345.6.11"])
myservs
5x2 DataFrame
| Row | serverName | ipAddress     |
|-----|------------|---------------|
| 1   | "elmo"     | "12.345.6.7"  |
| 2   | "bigBird"  | "12.345.6.8"  |
| 3   | "Oscar"    | "12.345.6.9"  |
| 4   | "gRover"   | "12.345.6.10" |
| 5   | "BERT"     | "12.345.6.11" |
```

How can I write the function to take a single parameter called `server`, case-insensitive match the `server` parameter in the `myservs[:serverName]` DataArray, and return the match's corresponding `ipAddress`?

In R this can be done by using

```
myservs$ipAddress[grep("server", myservs$serverName, ignore.case = T)]
```

I don't want it to matter if someone uses `ElMo` or `Elmo` as the `server`, or if the `serverName` is saved as `elmo` or `ELMO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I referenced how to accomplish the task in R and tried to do it using the `DataFrames` pkg, but I only did this because I'm coming from `R` and am just learning `Julia`. I asked a lot of questions from coworkers and the following is what we came up with:

> This task is much cleaner if I was to stop thinking in terms of
>   `vectors` in `R`. `Julia` runs plenty fast iterating through a loop.
>
> Even still, looping wouldn't be the best solution here. I was told to look into
>   [Dicts](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections/#Base.Dict) (check [here](http://www.scolvin.com/juliabyexample/#Dictionaries) for an example). `Dict()`, `zip()`, `haskey()`, and
>   `get()` blew my mind. These have many applications.
>
> My solution doesn't even need to use the `DataFrames` pkg, but instead
>   uses Julia's `Matrix` and `Array` data representations. By using `let`
>   we keep the global environment clutter free and the server name/ip
>   list stays hidden from view to those who are only running the
>   function.
>
> In the sample code, I'm recreating the server matrix every time, but in reality/practice I'll have a permission restricted delimited file that gets read every time. This is OK for now since the delimited files are small, but this may not be efficient or the best way to do it.

```
# ONLY ALLOW THE FUNCTION TO BE SEEN IN THE GLOBAL ENVIRONMENT
let global myIP

  # SERVER MATRIX
  myservers = ["elmo" "12.345.6.7"; "bigBird" "12.345.6.8";
               "Oscar" "12.345.6.9"; "gRover" "12.345.6.10";
               "BERT" "12.345.6.11"]

  # SERVER DICT
  servDict = Dict(zip(pmap(lowercase, myservers[:, 1]), myservers[:, 2]))

  # GET SERVER IP FUNCTION: INPUT = SERVER NAME; OUTPUT = IP ADDRESS
  function myIP(servername)
    sn = lowercase(servername)
    get(servDict, sn, "That name isn't in the server list.")
  end
end

​# Test it out
myIP("SLIMEY")
​#>​"That name isn't in the server list."

myIP("elMo"​)
#>​"12.345.6.7"
```

Comment: You may also want to explore Julia's [DataStructures.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl) for other, possibly higher performing lookups.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> myservs = DataFrame(serverName = ["elmo", "bigBird", "Oscar", "gRover", "BERT"],
                           ipAddress = ["12.345.6.7", "12.345.6.8", "12.345.6.9", "12.345.6.10", "12.345.6.11"])
5x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | serverName | ipAddress     |
|-----|------------|---------------|
| 1   | "elmo"     | "12.345.6.7"  |
| 2   | "bigBird"  | "12.345.6.8"  |
| 3   | "Oscar"    | "12.345.6.9"  |
| 4   | "gRover"   | "12.345.6.10" |
| 5   | "BERT"     | "12.345.6.11" |

julia> grep{T <: String}(pat::String, dat::DataArray{T}, opts::String = "") = Bool[isna(d) ? false : ismatch(Regex(pat, opts), d) for d in dat]
grep (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> myservs[:ipAddress][grep("bigbird", myservs[:serverName], "i")]
1-element DataArrays.DataArray{ASCIIString,1}:
 "12.345.6.8"
```

**EDIT**

This `grep` works faster on my platform.

```
julia> function grep{T <: String}(pat::String, dat::DataArray{T}, opts::String = "")
           myreg = Regex(pat, opts)
           return convert(Array{Bool}, map(d -> isna(d) ? false : ismatch(myreg, d), dat))
       end
```

Comment: Thank you. This works and that is an awesome grep function you wrote, but I was really looking for ideas on how to do this with a function that takes a single parameter and returns the IP. For example, `server_ip_address("GROVER")` or `server_ip_address("grover")` would both return `"12.345.6.10"`. I'm coming from R and am very new to Julia so I don't know the best way to accomplish this in Julia.

Comment: I modeled my answer from your example from `R`.  I'm not sure what you mean with your proposed function.  For example, how would the function know what `DataFrame` & column(s) to use?  Or did you want to define a specific function for just the case you've presented?

Comment: I also noticed that if you need higher performance, precomputing the `Regex` will greatly speed up `grep`.